# Ajax document.getElementById in innerHTML doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, innertext

```
function showSchedule() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = request.responseText;

            /* put alert to enroll submit button */
            document.getElementById("enroll").onclick = doIt;
        }
    }
}

function doIt() {
    alert("tu$a bastIn");
}
```

enroll is a button in coming with in request.responseText. I debug and see document.getElementById("enroll") is there (not null) but i can not assign doIt function. Any suggestions ?

Comment: where is request param in your function declaration?

Comment: request param is XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when `document.getElementById("enroll")` is not null, then you have several elements with this id (may also be detached).

you overwrite some content where this id is present or have used this somewhere else.